# Django - how can users create groups and add other users to see content provided by that group (like on facebook)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am creating a website with Django and I want My Users to be able to create there own groups (like on Facebook) and give permission to other members to see content only in that group can you give me a general idea of how I can go about coding that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very general question, so expect a very general answer. But what I get from your question is that you're looking for is how to design the models (database).

What I would do, is create a one to many relations between a table 'users' and 'group', then another one to many relation to some table 'content' and 'group'.

I know images are often quite ill received on here, but I don't know of any other way to share this, so here is one possible schema that I came up with.

[image: Model]

I would personally add more fields to these tables but this gives the general idea of what I think you're after.

After that, it is up to you how the users interract with the database. One implementation could be that users by default make content public but can decide to only share with one or many particular groups that they are in.

Hopefully this will get you started somewhere.